# Set F-Keys primary instead of special keys on Lenovo

Tags: lenovo

I have a new Lenovo E540 which has the special keys like volume change and such on the F-Keys [here](http://www.lenovo.com/images/gallery/1060x596/lenovo-laptop-thinkpad-e540-touch-keyboard-detail-8.jpg). So to actually use the F-Keys the FN has to be pressed to, so when using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> which is very inconvenient.
In the BIOS it is possible to swap the FN and Ctrl Keys so the F-Keys are primary again but then the functionality of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Key are really swapped! 
Is there probably a solution where the functionality of the FN and Ctrl key remain and the F-Keys are primary?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you press <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> it switches between the 2 modes. Visible with the led on the <kbd>FN</kbd> key.

It is easier to use <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> etc; when you want to use the special functions you can just use the <kbd>FN</kbd> key plus the <kbd>F</kbd> keys.

Comment: Amazing, had no idea how that worked, does it fine on my E550! It does not seem to work on my ThinkPad Bluetooth Keyboard sadly.

Comment: Doesn't work on my E50. There's not even an LED.

Comment: Works perfect on E580, thank you.

Comment: unless you swapped CTRL with FN keys in BIOS, then it will be: CTRL + ESC

Comment: It works on Dell 5530 as well.

Comment: This works on `Lenovo Thinkpad T460`.

Answer (score 7):

The answer saying to use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> didn't work for me. I'm using a Lenovo G50.

What did work was to shut down, press the tiny button next to the power socket using the end of a pen, go to the BIOS settings, and change the hotkey setting.

Now I have to hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> to access the media functions, and if I don't I get regular function key behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

in case you **swapped** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> with <kbd>FN</kbd> keys in BIOS, it is:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>

LED on <kbd>FN</kbd> key will still indicate the status