# How to change Fn keys behavior?

Tags: keyboard, lenovo

I have Ubuntu 14.04 in my Lenovo G500s. I googled and check last of solution but couldnt find how to change fn keys behaviour. I am a Centos user and new on Ubuntu. Please lead me to find place which I can change settings of Fn keys.

Comment: Did you have any solution for this on CentOS? Which keys are you trying to modify?

Comment: @alexander255 , on CentOS yes. I want to invert ALL Fn keys(I do not want to press fn for F3, F4, F5....etc). For example, if I click F3 it is volume up. However I am a programmer and I want to use F3 for view option...

Comment: Could you give us any insights on how you archived this behavior on CentOS?

Comment: @alexander255 hmm you mean go BIOS... so what if there is no option in BIOS? So it depends on Lenovo programmers.. I think I got it.. Thank you very much

Comment: I was assuming you where previously using CentOS on the machine with the FN key problem, but I that's not the case I guess? What was the previous operation system on the machine? Could you invert the FN keys there?

Comment: @alexander255 Actually.. I bought this pc 1 days ago... So I didnt do it before.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Lenovo website](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht072691) you may be able to achieve your desired behavior. You also might be able to [switch keyboard configuration using <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404275/set-f-keys-primary-instead-of-special-keys-on-lenovo). As the decision, which key presses to send to operating system is ultimately made by the [Embedded controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_controller) of the laptop, there is not a lot that can be done about this by operating system. You may also be able to remap most of the keys using [XModMap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap) in the display server but this might not work for all keys and will be some pain to set up.

Comment: Fn + Esc is not working and there is no option in BIOS Configuration Tab. As you said there is not a lot about OS. Maybe Lenovo programmer should consider this problem.

Comment: Definitely ask them! But don't expect too much: You already bought the machine and (as far as they are concerned) are "happy enough" with it (not a warranty case, etc.). Making a big form thread (with some other users) and annoying them until they release an update is usually your only option for this kind of stuff… ;-/